# I want to make a simple batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, minecraft

that opens Minecraft.exe, and logs in when clicked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, Is this what you want; it should work:

```
@echo off
"%cd%\minecraft.exe" username password serverip
```

edit the username, password and ip to your liking.

---

A Better Solution in my opinion:

Just figured it out, the batch file doesn't work, however; when set up as a shortcut it does! So create a new shortcut and for the path use this:

Format:

```
"<FilePath>" <username> <password> <server>
```

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Minecraft\Minecraft.exe" bobjones passchuck 123.123.123.123
```

Hope that works out for you, alot simpler then a bath file IMO.

also if you don't include IP, it just goes and logins in to minecraft. Stopping at the title screen.

Comment: Yes, but how would the batch file recognize those words as a username and password?

Comment: I just tried it out, and apparently, it wouldn't automatically log in, but when I entered the credentials, it did manage to connect to the server. Any way to figure out the rest?

Comment: i'll try it out and see if i can fix it

Comment: there, figured it out, it works with a shortcut, and it automatically works and logins!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Start_the_Minecraft_Server_.28.jar_version.29

To start the jar version of Minecraft on Windows, create a new file in Notepad, and paste in
java -Xms512M -Xmx1G -jar minecraft_server.jar
Save the file as startserver.bat, and place the file in the same folder as minecraft_server.jar. The .bat extension saves the file as a batch file.

Comment: This did not help me. I want a batch file that allows me to log in, you know, at the Minecraft Launcher start screen. When I double click it, I want it to open Minecraft with credentials already saved. And I plan on distributing this, so please don't say "just use "Remember password". Please help me achieve this.